# How to set InstallCondition for ExePackage in Chain based on file contents?

Tags: wix, burn, wix3.7

I have a Chain with following setup:
ExePackage1->MsiPackage1->ExePackage2->MsiPackage2

MsiPackage1 writes some values to file File1.

ExePackage2 has an InstallCondition which should be based on the contents of File1.

**How can I read the contents of File1 and set a property to be tested in InstallCondition?**

- I thought of util:FileSearch but it does help me with contents.
- Reading the contents in ExePackage2 with a custom action might be another approach but I would like to not even execute ExePackage2.

**UPDATE**
I have a Custom Action Library which is used by MsiPackage1 and MsiPackage2. Can it be extended to to host a CustomBA and do the required file reading and property setting?

Answer (score 3):

Burn doesn't work that way. It processes InstallCondition before the chain starts being applied so nothing that happens during the chain affects the rest of the chain.

Comment: Thanks for answering both variants of the question. Does a Custom BA make sense here or would a custom action be the way to go? If it is the custom action then how can I pass the information to the Chain?

Comment: You can set a package's action during planning. You can't modify the chain after that. A custom BA could abort the chain but not modify it.